# C++ Passing multiple objects to a function in threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, object

I have a problem with threading and passing multiple objects of the same class to the function. It is an external function, inside which I want to call a class method over each of the passed objects. 
I have tried passing a vector of objects, as well as a vector of pointers. I have also tried passing them by a reference.

Te specify, I have a "Gas" class, of which 3 objects are constructed in the code earlier. I call a lot of methods in threads before, so I guess that there is no issue with the class. 
The compiler returns very long error, the one with  _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>):

```
    .In file included from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/thread:39:0,
                 from ./src/../input.h:22,
                 from ./src/mass_source.cpp:12:
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/functional: In instantiation of 'struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*(int, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Ref::Gas> >))(int, std::vector<Ref::Gas>&)>':
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/thread:142:59:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(int, std::vector<Ref::Gas>&); _Args = {int&, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Ref::Gas, std::allocator<Ref::Gas> > >}]'
./src/mass_source.cpp:86:50:   required from here
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/functional:1505:61: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<void (*(int,  std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Ref::Gas> >))(int, std::vector<Ref::Gas>&)>'
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/functional:1526:9: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<void (*(int, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<Ref::Gas> >))(int, std::vector<Ref::Gas>&)>'
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
```

The error message comes from my "original" code, in which I have commented out all of the lines, which are not presented below. As it was reported to be confusing, here is an explanation:

```
from ./src/../input.h:22 - inclusion of thread library
from ./src/mass_source.cpp:12: - inclusion of the above input.h file
./src/mass_source.cpp:86: - calc_ms fucntion call
```

Below the class declaration is attached:

```
namespace Ref{
class Gas{
    public:
        Gas(const int id, const int& imax, const int& jmax){
            id_ = id;
            NX_ = imax;
            NR_ = jmax;
        }
        void set_ms(int m, double& mass_source){
            ms_[m] = mass_source;
        }


    private:
           int id_;
           int NX_, NR_;
           std::vector<double> ms_;
};
} //end of namespace
```

Code calling the function I have trouble with (creation of Gas objects and their pointers included):

```
using namespace Ref;
void calc_ms(int m, std::vector<Gas>& GAS);

int main(){     
    int i;
    std::vector<Gas> gases;
    std::vector<Gas*> ptr_gas(3);

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){                                     
        gases.push_back(Gas(i, grid));
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){                                     
        ptr_gas[i] = &gases[i];
    }
    std::vector<std::thread*> th_gas;
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        std::thread *thr = new std::thread(calc_ms, i, std::ref(gases));
        th_gas.push_back(thr);
    }
    for(auto &X : th_gas){
        X->join();
        delete X;
    }
    th_gas.clear();
}
```

And the calc_ms fucntion definition:

```
using namespace Ref;
void calc_ms(int m, std::vector<Gas>& GAS){
    double MassSourceCH4 = .... ;
    double MassSourceCO = .... ;
    double MassSourceCO2 = .... ;

    GAS[0].set_ms(m, MassSourceCH4);
    GAS[1].set_ms(m, MassSourceCO);
    GAS[2].set_ms(m, MassSourceCO2);

}
```

I have also tried passing gases by copy, and ptr_gas as a reference and copy.

COMMENT: The ms_ member of Gas class is resized somwhere else in the code, thus the assignment with using indexes is not a problem.

Comment: `calc_ms` doesn't take its second argument by reference, so no need to use `std::ref`.

Comment: I also don't see the need for the `ptr_gas` vector, or for you to use pointers to `std::thread`.

Comment: Please read the whole question carefully :) I tried many of the combinations, and obviously there should be reference operator in the function header, I just skipped it by mistake.

Comment: Then please try to create a [mcve] to show us, and show the error message from that example. You might even figure out the problem yourself while creating the example. And add a comment on the line in your example for any part of the error message referencing your code.

Comment: And you do have a proper function declaration of `calc_ms` before you create the threads?

Comment: Well a minimal reproducible example is created... what is more I attached the exact error message. What is the problem with what I have posted?

Comment: What line is line 86 of `mass_source.cpp`? How do you declare the `calc_ms` prototype? And it's not very minimal as it includes code that is irrelevant to the problem (like the unused `ptr_gas` vector). And most importantly, there's no way we can replicate the error.

Comment: Of course I have that, have you even checked the error message I attached?

Comment: As stated in question, I tried to substitute the std::vector<Gas> with std::vector<Gas*> and had the same error. I just put the creation of poitners vector to show how I did it. Those lines are obviously commented out, that I have not seen any reason to post them here? Man, what is your problem?

Comment: Where is the `calc_ms` ***declaration*** (or definition) in relation to your use of the symbol when creating the treads? Does the declaration match the actual function implementation?

Comment: it is in the file with main function. Do you know how to help me, or you will just try to prove me that I know nothing?

Comment: Well then why don't you *show* us? That needs to be part of the [mcve]. And again, which line is line 86 of the source file `mass_source.cpp`? A good [mcve] should be the smallest possible program that replicates the problem you ask about, and for it to be perfect we should be able to copy-paste it and replicate the problem ourselves, without us needing to write any extra code.

Comment: Here you go, I added everything. The line 86 is the call of the function. Just as it is further described in the error message.

Comment: Better, [now with quite some editing I can build it](https://godbolt.org/z/bJZ48W). But not replicate the error you get. Which kind of indicates that the source of the error is not in the code you show.

Comment: It comes exactly from the code I show, I do not really know what more I could do about this now

Comment: I managed to somewhat [replicate the error](https://godbolt.org/z/c33u73) if I changed `std::ref` to `std::cref`. Please check your actual code that you don't use `std::cref`.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I checked, and unfortunately it is std::ref...
I will try installing other compiler then. Maybe that is the issue...

Comment: I also get similar or related errors if I declare `calc_ms` without the reference, like `void calc_ms(int m, std::vector<Gas> GAS);` Or don't use `std::ref` at all (but you do so that's not the problem).

Comment: I'm sorry for maybe being a pest, but it's really hard to figure out build errors without having enough of the code. Replicating build errors with only small snippets could be very hard and frustrating, and often involves lot of guesswork. +1 for being patient at least. :)

Comment: So were you able to achieve any compilation without errors?

Comment: With some changes [yes I managed to build the code as you show it](https://godbolt.org/z/hxgvC2). The changes I made are commented.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version showing how to use threads correctly and how to pass a vector to a thread by reference:

```
class Gas { /*...*/ };

void calc_ms(int m, std::vector<Gas>& gases);

int main() {
    std::vector<Gas> gases;
    std::vector<std::thread> th_gas;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        th_gas.emplace_back(calc_ms, i, std::ref(gases));
    for(auto& t : th_gas)
        t.join();
    th_gas.clear();
}
```

Comment: @Padzak In that case I doubt anything will.

Comment: Well, the problem is not with the threads itself, but passing a vector of objects to the called fucntion

Comment: @Padzak This example passes the vector to `calc_ms` by reference. You should really pay careful attention, otherwise you cannot be helped.

Comment: What do you mean? I wanted to pass it by a reference.

Comment: @Padzak I risk repeating myself:  **this example passes the vector to `calc_ms` by reference.**

Comment: And now I risk repeating myself, what do you mean? It is exactly what I wanted to do. And it should be passed by a reference?

Comment: @Padzak You can check on e.g. cppreference how and why `std::reference_wrapper` is used when needing to pass things by reference to algorithms, threads, etc. `std::[c]ref()` creates an `std::reference_wrapper`.